# ASP Core 2.0 - Calling Controller Functions from a View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, web

I'm a complete beginner with ASP Core and web development in general, so I apologize if this is painfully obvious.

I am looking for a way to call a function that is present in my Controller from my View. This function would be called in reaction to the user clicking a button on their webpage.

Controller Function:

```
public ActionResult Change(int n)
    {
        ViewData["currentChoice"] = choiceArray[n];
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Choice currentPoint = ViewData["currentChoice"] as Choice;
    <h2>@currentPoint.text</h2>
}

//Button - Call Change function in the Controller
```

I have previously created a button that links to another page, in this case "Question/Change", but I do not want a redirect. The desired final result would simply update the text on the screen by changing the ViewData.

Comment: May be you should start reading MVC concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC Controller Actions(functions) are invoked through http requests that originate from your view in the form of anchor elements, AJAX calls, or form submissions.

MVC has nice helpers to generate correct URLs for anchor elements that map to your action of choice.

```
@{
Choice currentPoint = ViewData["currentChoice"] as Choice;
<h2>@currentPoint.text</h2>
}
<a href="@Url.Action("YourController", "Change")">Change</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
as you are using ASP.NET core so your anchor tag should be like this

```
<a asp-controller="YourControllerName" asp-action="Change" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="changeChoice()">Change</a>
```

add JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () 
    {
        function changeChoice() 
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/YourControllerName/Change
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('Successfully Updated'),
                        location.reload()
                    },
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```